# Possible missing firmware in debian

Tags: debian, xorg, nvidia, wayland, nouveau

I'm using Debian (Buster) with an Nvidia GT720 graphics card, and the `nouveau` module.

After running `apt upgrade`, I have this problem

```
...
Setting up linux-image-4.19.0-11-amd64 (4.19.146-1) ...
I: /vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-10-amd64
I: /initrd.img.old is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-10-amd64
I: /vmlinuz is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-11-amd64
I: /initrd.img is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-11-amd64
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-11-amd64
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp100/gr/sw_method_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp100/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp100/gr/sw_nonctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp100/gr/sw_ctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp100/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp100/gr/gpccs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp100/gr/gpccs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp100/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp100/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp100/gr/fecs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp100/gr/fecs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp100/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp100/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp100/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp100/acr/bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/sw_method_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/sw_nonctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/sw_ctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/gpccs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/gpccs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/fecs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/fecs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/acr/bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/sw_method_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/sw_nonctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/sw_ctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/gpccs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/gpccs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/fecs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/fecs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/acr/bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/sw_method_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/sw_nonctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/sw_ctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/gpccs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/gpccs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/fecs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/fecs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/acr/bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/sec2/image.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/sec2/desc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/nvdec/scrubber.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/gr/sw_method_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/gr/sw_nonctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/gr/sw_ctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/gr/gpccs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/gr/gpccs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/gr/fecs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/gr/fecs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/acr/unload_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/acr/bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/sec2/image.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/sec2/desc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/nvdec/scrubber.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/gr/sw_method_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/gr/sw_nonctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/gr/sw_ctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/gr/gpccs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/gr/gpccs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/gr/fecs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/gr/fecs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/acr/unload_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/acr/bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/sec2/image.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/sec2/desc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/nvdec/scrubber.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/gr/sw_method_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/gr/sw_nonctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/gr/sw_ctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/gr/gpccs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/gr/gpccs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/gr/fecs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/gr/fecs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/acr/unload_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/acr/bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/sec2/image.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/sec2/desc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/nvdec/scrubber.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/gr/sw_method_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/gr/sw_nonctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/gr/sw_ctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/gr/gpccs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/gr/gpccs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/gr/fecs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/gr/fecs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/acr/unload_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/acr/bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/sec2/image.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/sec2/desc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/nvdec/scrubber.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/sw_method_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/sw_nonctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/sw_ctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/gpccs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/gpccs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/fecs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/fecs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/unload_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/sec2/image.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/sec2/desc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/nvdec/scrubber.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/gr/sw_method_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/gr/sw_nonctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/gr/sw_ctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/gr/gpccs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/gr/gpccs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/gr/fecs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/gr/fecs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/acr/unload_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp108/acr/bl.bin for module nouveau
...
```

What's this?

Comment: Looks like this bug, https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=928672

Comment: Yes. I have a lot of graphics problems in Debian. such as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611875/gnome-maps-program-never-runs and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/609800/gnome-totem-never-runs

Comment: The complains of `update-initramfs` on the possible missing firmware are merely informational. You do not need all that firmware for your graphics card. Is the firmware that you need is listed among the possibly missing?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure apt is installing the latest nonfree packages by adding them to your sources.list. There are plenty of posts elsewhere telling you how to do that.

I had a similar issue with the message:
**Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau**
appearing when I updated Debian 10 on my Lenovo E530 laptop. I think there is a file missing from the current stable package. But I found this very useful page https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/CodeNames.html which tells you which software applies to which product. I believe this tells me that my GT630M graphics device requires the GF108 software and that the GV100 software only applies to the models NVIDIA Titan V and NVIDIA Quadro GV100. So I have ignored the error message.